# Android - Função getX() não funciona

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando criar um jogo usando java sem o uso de outras bibliotecas. Consegui fazer tudo que precisava até agora porém não estou conseguindo usar a função getX() no ImageView controlado pelo jogador nesse trecho:

```
ImageView player = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player);

if(player.getX() == 80){
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ";)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

}else{
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ";(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}
```

O que tem de errado?

Comment: Está muito vago. O que você quer fazer? O que a função `getX()` deveria fazer? Qual é resposta que você está esperando?

Comment: Quero que certa função seja executada apenas quando a posição x da ImageView for 80, porém não consegui resultados.

Comment: A questão é que mesmo a ImageView estando na posição 80, a função não é executada.